# How to access internet on my firefox through ssh remote?

Tags: networking, firefox, ssh, terminal, wget

Alright, I'm completely *blank* into this weird world.

Let's say, I can access a ssh remote server(A server which has `no GUI` and `no monitor` but have `internet` connection) using terminal in ubuntu(Which is my PC with GUI). I just don't have Internet connection on my PC but could access server's internet(Which has no GUI and no monitor) using `Elink` text based browser only in terminal.

I could also save any file onto that ssh remote server using `wget` command into terminal. It doesn't save file into my hard drive because i'm accessing another server(Which has no GUI).

But my wish is to access that server's(Which has no GUI) Internet onto my firefox. I'm getting stuck with elink's browser(A text based shi* browser). Kindly let me know, Is it possible to access that internet on my Firefox?

Help surely would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with `SOCKS` proxy. Use `-D` option With `OpenSSH` `ssh` client:

```
ssh -fND 12000 <REMOTE_IP>
```

It will create a local `SOCKS` proxy on port `12000`, you can choose another port if you wish. `-fN` is to put `ssh` command in background as all we want to do is just to create `SOCKS` proxy. In `firefox` go to `Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Network->Settings`, check `Manual proxy configuration`, put `localhost` in `SOCKS host` and put `12000` in `Port` next to it. From now you should be able to access Internet in `firefox` via the remote host. This a classical form of *tunneling*. It's especially useful for circumventing over-eager firewalls or for secure connections in internet cafes etc. If you feel you will it more often you can automate the whole process in `Firefox` using [mozrepl addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/). For example, I use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ssh -4 -fND 12000 home

# modify firefox settings with mozrepl

(echo "prefs = Components.classes[\"@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1\"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch)"; echo "prefs.setIntPref(\"network.proxy.type\", \"1\")"; sleep 2) | telnet 127.0.0.1 4242 > /dev/null

# got to http://v4.ident.me/ to make sure that IP changed
(echo "content.location.href = 'http://v4.ident.me/'"; sleep 2) | telnet 127.0.0.1 4242 > /dev/null
```

Also note that you can use your locally created `SOCKS` proxy in many other programs such as e-mail clients that do not support `SOCKS` proxy out of the box using `tsocks` wrapper.

Comment: Suppose i'm able to connect my server on termianl using `ssh -a aroraarora`.. Then how would i connect it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. As I said: `ssh -fND 12000 aroraarora`. Add `-a` if you need it.

Comment: Suppose, I do connect my server using `rhc` let's say.. `rhc ssh -a aroraarora`.. then how would i connect it with firefox?

Comment: I have never heard about `rhc`. You only asked about `ssh`. Does `ssh` method work for you? If this `rhc` tool is a wrapper for `ssh` it also might work.

Comment: Okay dude.. Let me try first, I'd get back to accept your answer once it gets connected.